# Reading specific values from a text file into an array with node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a text file, in which I have data in the form:

```
2014-5-2 17:42:44: Temperature 23.6 C, Humidity 27.4 % RH, Light 624
2014-5-2 17:42:46: Temperature 23.6 C, Humidity 27.4 % RH, Light 621
2014-5-2 17:42:48: Temperature 23.6 C, Humidity 27.3 % RH, Light 631
2014-5-2 17:42:50: Temperature 23.6 C, Humidity 27.3 % RH, Light 623
2014-5-2 17:42:52: Temperature 23.7 C, Humidity 27.3 % RH, Light 622
2014-5-2 17:42:54: Temperature 23.6 C, Humidity 27.4 % RH, Light 649
2014-5-2 17:42:56: Temperature 23.7 C, Humidity 27.3 % RH, Light 637
```

I need to read the values in 3 arrays - Temperature, Humidity and Light. Thus, the temperature array would have values like this:

[ 23.6, 23.6, 23.6, 23.6, 23.7, ...]

It would be the same way for the humidity and light arrays.

Is there a way to read such a text file and put the values in the array using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and parse it line by line. End line symbol `\n` might be separator.

Then all you need is parse necessary numbers from each line.

```
var fs  = require('fs');

fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var temperature = [],
        humidity = [],
        light = [];

    data.split(/\n/).forEach( function( item ) {
        temperature.push( Number( item.match(/Temperature(.\d+[.]\d+)/)[1] ) );

        // do the same for other ones
    });
});
```